# Setting multiple variables in one line

Tags: c#

In perl I can define a bunch of variables in 1 line:

```
my value=0;
my (a,b,c)=value;
```

is there some similar C# way of doing the same? here is what I have:

```
const bool free = true;
bool t1,t2,t3;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //t1,t2,t3=free;
}
```

Comment: C# does not support *assignment decomposition*. Only a single value can be assigned to a single variable with `=` (although the `a=b` expression itself yields the value of `b`). The equivalent is, therefore, multiple assignments.

Comment: Side note: please avoid long unrelated text about your fate, opinions and similar other topic not related to your question (including "I'm new here" and "thank you notes") in posts on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can do t1 = t2 = t3 = free; However, it really makes it much harder to read. I would not recommend it.

Comment: Note that this is not equivalent to `my (a,b,c)=value` or similar constructs as may be found in Perl, Python, Ruby, or Scala which support decomposition during assignment. Rather the same value (e.g. the result of evaluating `free`) is assigned to all the variables (e.g. `t1`, `t2`, `t3`). With few exceptions (such as in a while or default-value construct) I find this behavior only of moderate use. In C#, `t1 = t2 = t3 = value` is equivalent to `t1 = (t2 = (t3 = value))` as the assignment operator is rightward associative and evaluates to the value assigned but is otherwise not very special.

Comment: @user2864740 the phrase is "destructuring assignment"

Answer (score 3):

C# does not support full destructuring assignment.  Thus, there is no C# equivalent of

```
my @v = (1,3,5);
my ($a,$b,$c) = @v;
```

However, as pointed out by @Guthwulf, in the case of a scalar you can write `t1 = t2 = t3 = free` and it will assign the same value to each element.