# Setting multiple labels with same text

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

We do internatializing (sp?) by this:

```
<asp:Label ID="labelPhone" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Then in the aspx.cs:

```
labelPhone.Text = (string)GetGlobalResourceObject("lang", "Phone") + ":";
```

But then if there are more labels I have to repeat:

```
labelPhone2.Text = (string)GetGlobalResourceObject("lang", "Phone") + ":";
labelPhone3.Text = (string)GetGlobalResourceObject("lang", "Phone") + ":";
```

Can this be avoided?

Like jQuery giving all identival labels the same class, then assigning text to that class:

```
 $(".phonelabel").text("Telefon:");
```

Comment: Have you checked how ASP.NET localization works? You *don't* need to set individual labels. You could refer to the resource key directly, eg: `Text="<%$ Resources:Label1TextKey %>"`. You could also use *templates*  for specific fields, eg a Phone template that includes the localized label and field.

Comment: Where does `GetGlobalResourceObject` come from? Have you tried using [Resource Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f.aspx) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Panagiotis write:

```
 <asp:Label runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Lang, Phone %> "  CssClass="box" />
```

If the comment were an answer, i would have selected it as the winner ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can perform single statement assignment like this:

```
labelPhone.Text = labelPhone2.Text = labelPhone3.Text =
(string)GetGlobalResourceObject("lang", "Phone") + ":";
```

or you can do it in a loop:

```
Label[] labels = new[] { labelPhone, labelPhone2, labelPhone3 };
Array.ForEach(labels, x => { x.Text = 
          (string)GetGlobalResourceObject("lang", "Phone") + ":"; });
```

Comment: OK, I'll go for the first, but I would have preferred I would have been able to just add a new phone label without having to add it to the list of assignments.

Comment: I don't think you can check out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417839/setting-multiple-variables-in-one-line

Comment: @LeifNeland have you checked how localization works in ASP.NET? You *don't* need to set individual labels, nor do it in the code-behind.

Comment: There may be a way to do it using reflection. I will look into it if I have time.

Comment: There is no need for reflection. This is a *localization* question. ASP.NET provides several mechanisms. For example, the text can be set on the tag itself : `Text="<%$ Resources:Label1TextKey %>"`.

Comment: Change this to an answer, @Panagiotis, I'll mark you for it.

Answer (score 0):

u can use this extension method.

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void ForControls<T>(this Control ctrl, Func<T, bool> where, Action<T> action) where T : Control
    {
        if (ctrl is T)
            if (where(ctrl as T))
                action(ctrl as T);
        foreach (Control childControl in ctrl.Controls)
        {
            childControl.ForControls(where, action);
        }
    }
}
```

using..

```
            this.ForControls<Label>(
            // you can define any other condition
            c => c.ID.StartsWith("labelPhone"),
            // you can make any other process for this controll
            c => c.Text = (string)GetGlobalResourceObject("lang", "Phone") + ":");
```